# Why can't clang++ find a matching basic_string constructor?

Tags: c++

When compiling my tests in CI on macOS 11, I get an error:

> no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')

for this line:

```cpp
std::string actual(proc_ptrs.begin(), proc_ptrs.end());
            ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I intend for it to use the constructor numbered 6 on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). My code requires C++11 or greater, so we can limit our discussion to the (since C++11) variant of the constructor.

`proc_ptrs.begin()` and `proc_ptrs.end()` are both `Getargv::Iterator<char>` that satisfy the requirements for a `contiguous_iterator` (or `random_access_iterator` for versions of C++ < 20). Which, from reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator, I believe should imply they satisfy the requirements of `LegacyInputIterator`, yet clang++ cannot seem to tell this?

I've cut `/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` from the beginning of the path of each header file, to save space.

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:884:9: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _InputIterator = Getargv::Iterator<char>]: no member named '_EnableIfImpl' in 'std::_MetaBase<false>'
        basic_string(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last);
        ^
```

The iterator template is defined here:

https://github.com/getargv/getargv.cpp/blob/main/include/iter.hpp

and then instantiated with `using Iterator = Iterator<char>;` in my struct.

Full error text:

```
src/lib_unit_tests.cpp:415:36: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')
                       std::string actual(proc_ptrs.begin(), proc_ptrs.end());
                                   ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/criterion/internal/assert.h:718:91: note: expanded from macro 'cr_expect_no_throw'
#define cr_expect_no_throw(...)      CR_EXPAND(cr_assert_no_throw_va_(CR_FAIL_CONTINUES_, __VA_ARGS__))
                                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/criterion/internal/assert.h:472:39: note: expanded from macro 'cr_assert_no_throw_va_'
                CR_VA_HEAD(CR_VA_TAIL(__VA_ARGS__)),             \
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/criterion/internal/preprocess.h:61:103: note: expanded from macro 'CR_VA_TAIL'
#define CR_VA_TAIL(...)                   CR_EXPAND(CR_VA_TAIL_HELPER(CR_VA_TAIL_SELECT(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__))
                                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 13 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/include/criterion/internal/assert.h:460:9: note: expanded from macro 'cr_assert_no_throw_'
        Statement;                                           \
        ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/criterion/internal/preprocess.h:35:43: note: expanded from macro 'CR_EXPAND'
#define CR_EXPAND(x)                      x
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/criterion/internal/preprocess.h:35:43: note: expanded from macro 'CR_EXPAND'
#define CR_EXPAND(x)                      x
                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:822:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'const std::string' for 1st argument
    basic_string(const basic_string& __str, const allocator_type& __a);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:834:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'std::string' for 1st argument
    basic_string(basic_string&& __str, const allocator_type& __a);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:849:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'const char *' for 1st argument
        basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Allocator& __a);
        ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:852:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'const char *' for 1st argument
    basic_string(const _CharT* __s, size_type __n);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:856:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'std::basic_string<char>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') for 1st argument
    basic_string(size_type __n, _CharT __c);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:865:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'const std::string' for 1st argument
    basic_string(const basic_string& __str, size_type __pos,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:892:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Argv::Iterator' (aka 'Iterator<char>') to 'initializer_list<char>' for 1st argument
    basic_string(initializer_list<_CharT> __il, const _Allocator& __a);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:880:18: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = Getargv::Iterator<char>]: no member named '_EnableIfImpl' in 'std::_MetaBase<false>'
        explicit basic_string(const _Tp& __t, const allocator_type& __a);
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:884:9: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _InputIterator = Getargv::Iterator<char>]: no member named '_EnableIfImpl' in 'std::_MetaBase<false>'
        basic_string(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last);
        ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:814:40: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__a', but 2 arguments were provided
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit basic_string(const allocator_type& __a)
                                       ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:821:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__str', but 2 arguments were provided
    basic_string(const basic_string& __str);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:826:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__str', but 2 arguments were provided
    basic_string(basic_string&& __str)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:839:5: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__s', but 2 arguments were provided
    basic_string(const _CharT* __s) : __r_(__default_init_tag(), __default_init_tag()) {
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:876:18: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__t', but 2 arguments were provided
        explicit basic_string(const _Tp& __t);
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:890:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__il', but 2 arguments were provided
    basic_string(initializer_list<_CharT> __il);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:854:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
    basic_string(const _CharT* __s, size_type __n, const _Allocator& __a);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:860:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
        basic_string(size_type __n, _CharT __c, const _Allocator& __a);
        ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:887:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
        basic_string(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, const allocator_type& __a);
        ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:811:31: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY basic_string()
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:862:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires at least 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
    basic_string(const basic_string& __str, size_type __pos, size_type __n,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:870:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires at least 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
        basic_string(const _Tp& __t, size_type __pos, size_type __n,
        ^
```

Comment: The full error message will tell you what it thinks `proc_ptrs.begin()` and `proc_ptrs.end()` return, and there's almost always important details in that information. I recommend reproducing the whole error, but feel free to skip the crawl of possible-but-rejected candidates.

Comment: Also worth backing up the code and carving it down to a [mre] (MRE). You'll probably find the problem a few divide-and-conquer passes into making the MRE, but if you don't you'll have an excellent example we and future askers can use to investigate the problem.

Comment: The error message points out that an `_EnableIfImpl` member is missing (presumably inside a `std::enable_if` check), which implies that the constructor is looking for something that is missing in the implementation of `Getargv::Iterator<char>`, thus it is not a viable candidate.

Comment: @user4581301 added full error text.

Comment: Interesting and I stand corrected. The message isn't providing the information I expected in the form I expected, and the answer is in fact in the crawl, specifically the portion you called out. My apologies.

Comment: Have a look at `/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:884` to see which SFINAE test is evaluating to `false`.

Comment: @user17732522 ok that's a 10GB download so it'll take me a beat.

Comment: Reproducible with upstream Clang 12 (but not after) when C++20 is enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/bb7E8d5fd

Comment: `Getargv::Iterator<>` is not a valid iterator in C++20, because the mandatory type field `iterator_category` exist only for C++ version before 202002L (line 29 of iter.hpp file)

Comment: @dalfaB That's not correct. Since C++20 `iterator_category` is defaulted via `std::iterator_traits`. This is a bug in libc++ for C++20 that seems to have been fixed with upstream version 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In libc++ upstream version 12 (which the XCode version seems to be based on) the C++20 changes to `std::iterator_traits` haven't been implemented yet.

They were merged with https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/9f01ac3b3257ab925a2b1229dba19e3eb86a706b for version 13.

The implementation of the iterator you are linking assumes that if compiled for C++20 these changes have been implemented as well.

In particular in C++20 it is not necessary to explicitly specify `iterator_category` anymore since `std::iterator_traits` will default it.

This doesn't work without the C++20 changes for `std::iterator_traits` and so libc++ falsely assumes that the type doesn't satisfy the Cpp17Iterator concept, effectively using the C++17 definitions instead of the C++20 ones although the library assumes the C++20 definitions when compiling in C++20 mode.

Comment: Ok so I'll just default to c++ 17 for clang < 13. Sounds good.